# Moodle email templates

Tags: php, moodle

I am working on a Learning Management System build upon Moodle. I want to add an email header and footer for each email.

I did some change in Moodle for adding an image in ./lib/moodlelib.php as follows:

```
function email_to_user($user, $from, $subject, $messagetext, $messagehtml = '', $attachment = '', $attachname = '',
                       $usetrueaddress = true, $replyto = '', $replytoname = '', $wordwrapwidth = 79) {

    global $CFG, $PAGE, $SITE;
    // Append image at top
    if($messagehtml){
        $tmp = $messagehtml;

       // Added image here
       $messagehtml = '<img src="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/images/logo.png" alt="LMS" /><br/>';

       // $messagehtml = $image;
        $messagehtml .= $tmp;
    }
    if($messagetext){
        $tmp = $messagetext;
        // Added image here
        $messagetext = '<img src="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/images/logo.png" alt="LMS" /><br/>';
       // $messagehtml = $image;
        $messagetext .= $tmp;
    }   
  ....................
```

but I want the header and footer as fixed templates. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a message header in a [language file](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/String_API) (in English either directly under `/lang/en` or in a plugin) and then add the following string in the language file:

```
$string ['message_header'] = '<p> write here whatever your style and HTML structure you want in your header</p>
adding your image as well <img src="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/images/logo.png" alt="LMS" />';
```

Then you could write a string for your footer as well:

```
$string ['message_footer'] = 'Your HTML footer here';
```

And finally you could insert your strings in the message:

```
$message = 'here your body';

// insert message header - if your language string is in /lang/moodle.php:

$message = get_string ( 'message_header') . $message;

// insert message footer - if your language string is in your /local/myplugin:

$message .= get_string ( 'message_footer', 'local_my_plugin' );
```

This way your header and footer may be customized at will if you change them directly  in the language file (or, in the DB. See [here](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Language_customisation)).

Answer (score 4):

a little bit too late, but i hope it helps others:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themed_emails just look for e-mail templates in /var/www/html/moodle/lib/templates. The template with a name email_html.mustache should be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `pix` keyword specified at [Moodle Dev Template Documentation](https://moodledev.io/docs/guides/templates#pix).

With this feature you can upload images through theme folder (theme/yourtheme/pix/logo.png), or other modules like, core, etc.

Example using custom theme boost based:

```
{{#pix}} logo, theme_yourtheme, Alt Text {{/pix}}
```

Example using core module:

```
{{#pix}} logo, core, Alt Text {{/pix}}
```

**Attention:** Templates can be found at `lib/templates` folder. e.g.:

- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_401_STABLE/lib/templates/sticky_footer.mustache
- Override using theme: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_401_STABLE/theme/boost/templates/core/sticky_footer.mustache